# Nasm x86 modified char in array

Tags: arrays, assembly, char, x86, nasm

I have defined an array is SECTION .bss like this :

```
TextLenght EQU 1024 ; Define length of a line of  text data
Text resb TextLenght ; Define array to hold text
```

Then i use getchar to put the char from a file using stdin like this :

```
all getchar ; call getchar to get input from stdin, char is save in eax 
cmp eax, -1
jle Done     ; if return -1, we at EOF
mov [Text+esi], eax; put char from eax into array
add esi, 4    ; increase array index
jmp read   ; loop back this function
```

So how would i go about shifting the char in Text up one letter so that 'a' become 'b' ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 1 to `eax` before you `move` it into the array.  Or, if you have already put it in the array, and register X is 4 times the index, you can just do

```
add [Text+X], 1
```

Comment: is there any way to modify the content of the array directly ?